# Making a group of $p$ people with $n$ available nationalities

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, integer-partitions

Making a group of p people using m out of n available nationalities can be one of these two scenarios;

$m \le p \le n$ or $m \le n \le p$.

> Using p,m, and n, how to evaluate the number of ways of making a group
>   of p people using m out of n available nationalities?

Comment: what is your attempt?

Comment: @Klangen I could not reach to the way. I think there is no exact formula for that. And I think it is related to partitions (Ramanujan partitions asymptotic formula should be used I think).